# How can I lower the view into the safe area?

Tags: swift, snapkit

I'm practicing using snapkit to place ui of view.
However, I tried many things to move the red box into the safe area under the notch, but I couldn't find a way.

[image]
[image]

```
    var redView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.addSubview(redView)
        
        redView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        redView.snp.makeConstraints{ make in
            make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaInsets.top)
            make.size.width.height.equalTo(100)
            make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left)
        }
```

here is my code.
Why doesn't it still come into the safe area even if I designate the red box tower as Safe Area Insets.top?
I would appreciate it if you could let me know my mistake.

Comment: https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit/issues/448 or https://svasilevkin.wordpress.com/2019/01/11/snapkit-safe-area-and-layout-guide-difference/ might help

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
redView.snp.makeConstraints{ make in
    make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top)
    make.size.width.height.equalTo(100)
    make.left.equalTo(view.snp.left)
}
```

Comment: Or even shorter with `make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide)` :)